# How to create a java application executable (.exe) using Spring-MVC, Spring-Data and postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, build, jar

I created a .jar of a java application using Spring-MVC.

When I connected to the Postgresql database the .jar file is no longer working.

How to create the .jar with the embedded Postgresql? Please help me.

Comment: "no longer working" do you have any error? If so, add it to the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70016984/edit) it.

Comment: Your question is too general. Where did you find any problems? What have you done?

Comment: You cannot embed PostgreSQL in a JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot with PostgreSQL in Docker compose.  Spring boot application into a docker image, package the application as a jar file, create docker compose file( this contains postgres image).

Comment: I will try, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Let me know if you need any further help. If I have time would create a sample hello world Postgres spring boot application. I think there were plenty of examples already in a git repository.

Comment: Thank you very much friend.

I've never used the docker and it's still a little difficult to adapt, but I'm studying if you have a tutorial that makes me easier, you can also send it to me, Thank you.

Comment: No problem, it's easy to adapt. If you are completely new to docker go through some of the basic videos in youtube(there are plenty).    you can install docker on your windows machine or play here (https://labs.play-with-docker.com/) .  Docker cheat sheet (https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/d8/2019-09/docker-cheat-sheet.pdf).  Docker tutorial(https://www.docker.com/101-tutorial), Play with docker(https://training.play-with-docker.com/)

Comment: I learned about the docker it makes it much easier but it is not suitable for a commercial application because my application will be used in clients outside my country and with the dock the installation process will not be practical.
I saw another article that explains how to make executable for java applications using Inno Setup.
and on the postgres website I found this link: [https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/13080/PostgreSQL_7_5_for_Windows.iss]

I think the problem will be solved.

@Uday I am very grateful for your opinions and it has helped me, Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, good analysis.